# How to check whether a typedArray is modified in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In my situation there is a function named `caculateTypedArray()` which called very frequently.

```
function caculateTypedArray(array){
    if (array.isModified){
        // Goto A
    }else{
        // Goto B
    }
}
```

I want to check if the typedArray parameter is modified against it first coming.

For example:

```
function caculateTypedArray(array){
    if (array.isModified){
        // Goto A
    }else{
        // Goto B
    }
}

var f32Arr = new Float32Array([1, 2, 3]);
caculateTypedArray(f32Arr); //Goto B

f32Arr[0] = 2;
caculateTypedArray(f32Arr); //Goto A
//Or other form of modification
f32Arr.set([4, 5], 1); //Goto A
```

Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: If you have control over what kind of input `calculateTypedArray` takes, I think your best bet is to encapsulate the Float32Array in an object that takes care of `isModified`

Comment: I can't control the input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. ES6: Proxy

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

var proxy = new Proxy( array , {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) { 
    // handle your event management here 
    return thisArg[target].apply(this, argumentList);
  },

  deleteProperty: function(target, property) {},
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {}  
});

// now just use 
proxy[0]; // to trigger apply
```

2. ES5: Define Property

```
Object.defineProperty(myArray, "push", {
  enumerable: false, // false for...in
  writable: false, // Array.push = overwrite?
  value: function (...args)
    {
        let result = Array.prototype.push.apply(this, args); // Original push() 

        // handle your event management here 

        return result; // Original push() implementation
    }
});
```